# Serialización o reutilización de una sesión Appium en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialización, appium, pickle

Estoy teniendo problemas en la serializaciópn de un objeto de Appium con pickle, el error que me lanza es:

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'PoolManager.**init**..'

El código es:

```
import pickle
        
data1_string = pickle.dumps(self.bot)

data2 = pickle.loads(data1_string)
print(data2.page_source)
```

Y entonces no me funciona y creo que es porque no se puede. Entonces leío esta referencia: https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/

Y es una forma de utilizar Selenium con una sesion ID, y bueno Appium usa Selenium, y si funciona, pero hay un gran problema. Y es que cuando hago lo que dice en esa referencia, no actua de la misma manera. Ahí dice que en el caso de Selenium en puro navegador, se puede reutilizar el navegador que ya estava activo sin tener que ir nuevamente a abrir chromdriver ni la web (url), pero en Appium si yo pongo `desired_capabilities = {}` que es lo que el dice que hagamos pues Appium dice que tengo que agregar `platformName`. Entonces lo agrego y tal... Pero sucede que despues me dice que tengo que agregar `packageName` y lo general de la app que quiero abrir y ahí es el problema. Que cuando le doy eso vuelve a abrir la app, y yo necesito controlar la app en el estado que ya estaba no abrirla y hacer todo de nuevo. A ver si alguien sabe ayudarme, solo me falta eso. La verdad nunca tube problemas con ningun modulo etc... Todo lo aprendo bien solo, pero en este caso se me ha hecho complicado como resolverlo.

La verdad sí tengo una solución, lo que pasa es que seria escribir un modulo hecho desde cero con uiautomator para el manejo de xlml y ciertas cosas para aplicar la busqueda por xpath etc... Y entonces en este caso sí puedo, sino encuentro una forma con appium voy a tener que literalmente mejorar mi propio modulo de automatización para teléfonos, pues si appium no permite la reutilización de sessiones entonces no me sirve para este proyecto. Gracias por leer, cualquier cosa me dejan saber.